# finding the length of the altitude of the rhombus

Tags: geometry

the lengh of the side of a rhombus is given as $5\sqrt2$. if two of its opposites vertices have coordinates $(3,-4)$ and $(1,2)$. find the lengh of the altitude of the rhombus?

i was trying this question  , i got anwer $\sqrt{37}$  by using the distance formula, , i think  $\sqrt{37}$ is not altitude  of rhombus. im very confuse how to find altitude of rhombus, i dont know from where i have to start...

if anbody help me,, i would be very thankful to him

i have no idea and hint
if any body pliz help me ,,,,i would be very thankful to him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start finding the shorter diagonal $AC$

If we have $A(3,-4)$ and $C(1,2)$ then $AC=\sqrt{40}=2\sqrt{10}$

Call $O$ the midpoint of $AC$ and $B$ and $D$ the other vertices. From Pythagoras theorem $OB=\sqrt{BC^2-OC^2}=\sqrt{50-10}=\sqrt{40}=2\sqrt{10}$

The larger diagonal is $BD=4\sqrt{10}$ so the area of the rhombus is $\mathcal{A}=40$ and the height of the rhombus is $h=\dfrac{\mathcal{A}}{BC}=\dfrac{40}{5\sqrt{2}}=4\sqrt{2}$

$h=4\sqrt 2$

[image]

Comment: thanks u so much@ raffaele love u for perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

HINT.

1) The distance between given vertices is not $\sqrt{37}$: please revise your calculation.

2) You are given the sides of the rhombus and one of its diagonals, but it is easy to find the other diagonal (Pythagora's theorem).

3) Once you have both diagonals, you can find the area of the rhombus and then divide by the side to get the altitude.

Comment: u r coorect @ aretino  special thank to u ,, pliz   give me detail prove  as im very weak in geometry